# Parallel resistors connected only on one side?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance, current-measurement, parallel, basic

In this diagram,

[image]

with four different resistors, in the lower circuit, we know that the voltage across all resistors is the same, and the currents are different. With the formula 1/Rn = 1/R1 + 1/R2 + 1/R3 + 1/R4, we get the total resistance and then current.

What is the voltages, currents, total resistance, and total current, and total voltage(?) in the upper circuit, assuming the ground or any other equivalent, somehow connects the four currents back to the battery without let them join to balance the voltage.

The motive behind the question: I want to know if the connection at the back of parallelly connected resistors is the reason they end up having the same voltage across them. Meaning the current running out of one low resistance resistor actually at the very first microseconds of the circuit running will get from the back end of said resistor all the way to the front end of another high resistance resistor to balance the voltage quickly. I don't know how to put the question better, I am totally new to the topic, and it's been less than two weeks since I opened the first thing about electronics, I came from software background and needed this to understand some key hardware behaviors.

My regards.

Comment: Those two circuit diagrams are identical.

Comment: @mkeith please read the entire text, and don't just look at the diagram

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking--it's pretty hard to parse--but mkeith is right, the two circuit diagrams represent identical circuits.

Comment: The voltage is the same across all resistors in parallel because the wires have negligible voltage drop. All points on the wire are just about at the same voltage (ideally, but not always true in the real world). I am having trouble understanding your question. Having two identical wire diagrams is not helping explain it. It just makes the question even more confusing.

Comment: I feel like you should find a very simple but conceptually correct field-based explanation of voltage, current, resistance and Ohm's law. The kind that you find in text books. I think it would clear a lot of things up.

Comment: @mkeith I appreciate your input.

Comment: for low frequency, these circuits are identical. for high frequency, there can indeed be different voltages at different points in a single schematic node (e.g. ground) which has a large physical extent. Read more e.g. here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/592386/why-is-ground-meaningless-in-high-speed-circuits-whereas-more-important-is-the-p/592398#592398

Comment: @tobalt that's a great help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a schematic, all conductors labelled ground are assumed to be connected to an ideal 0 V.

That means the ground conductors, and all wires connected to them, up to the left-hand end of the batteries, and the right-hand end of the resistors, are all at 0 V.

The conductors in the middle of the diagram between the battery and the resistors will be at Vbat with respect to ground.

You should be able to see therefore that all resistors have a voltage of Vbat across them. Corresponding resistors will be behaving identically, whether in the upper or lower diagram.

It does not matter what path the current takes from the ends of the resistors to the terminal labelled ground, as long as it flows along ideal conductors.

When in the real world we want to take account of the length, or resistance, or other non-idealities of conductors, or what happens in the first microsecond of connection, then we add more components to the schematic to represent those.

But that is not a subject for a 2-weeks in student, learn to walk before you run. I'd strongly recommend that some of that learning be with resistors, a battery and a DMM on a benchtop, and not just in theory. Compared to resistors above 100 Ω, all wires are 'ideal'.